# What is the etymology behind the phrase "bad dope"?

Tags: etymology, phrases

What is the etymology behind the phrase "bad dope", as in these examples:

- ["This efficiency stuff is bad dope when it makes a man forget his meals!"](http://books.google.com/books?id=sicDAAAAMBAJ&lpg=PA117&ots=j-FNdLREqV&dq=information%20%22bad%20dope%22&pg=PA117#v=onepage&q=information%20%22bad%20dope%22&f=false)
- [HEADLINE: "Computer given bad dope"](http://news.google.com/newspapers?nid=1338&dat=19810912&id=PkoaAAAAIBAJ&sjid=WycEAAAAIBAJ&pg=6550,3322884)
- [Bad Dope: “But Case Shiller Data is 2 Months Old”](http://www.ritholtz.com/blog/2012/04/canard-but-case-shiller-data-is-2-months-old/)

Comment: Please can you give an example with context?

Answer (score 3):

> [***dope***](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?allowed_in_frame=0&search=dope&searchmode=none) : (n.) 1807, American English, "sauce, gravy, thick liquid," from Dutch doop "thick dipping sauce," from doopen "to dip" (cf. dip (v.)). Extension to "drug" is 1889, from practice of smoking semi-liquid opium preparation. Meaning "foolish, stupid person" is older (1851) and may have a sense of "thick-headed." Sense of "inside information" (1901) may come from knowing before the race which horse had been drugged to influence performance. Dope-fiend is attested from 1896.

I am assuming that by *bad dope* you mean nothing more than *bad drugs* and from that standpoint I don't think there is a separate etymology for the pair.
It'd be the same as asking for the etymology of *brick house*.